# Run xctestrun from command prompt in windows

Tags: ios, xcuitest

How to run xctestrun in an ios device connected through usb from command prompt in windows.. This can be achieved in a mac using the xcodebuild command inbuild within the xCode IDE. Need similar approach in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run those from a Mac.

Comment: I see there is an alternative called [xcbuild](https://github.com/facebook/xcbuild) which can be run from windows... i want something similar to this..

Comment: You need the xcuitest framework ported to windows, which is very unlikely to happen without action by Microsoft and Apple, since it is proprietary code owned by Apple.